# No response from Philips Hue debug tool

Tags: philips-hue

i'm trying to make a request about the debug/clip.html tool on my Philips Hue Bridge.
Unfortunately I don't get an answer back at all.

I try the following: 
"/api/newdeveloper" and GET.

But the answer always remains empty.
Does anyone know where the problem can be?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's a confirmed [bug](https://developers.meethue.com/forum/t/clip-api-debugger-stopped-working-after-bridge-firmware-update/6260) (login required). A temporary solution is to install [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-content-security/ieelmcmcagommplceebfedjlakkhpden?hl=en) plugin for Chrome to disable Content Security Policy.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than wait for firmware updates and/or disabling important browser security features, I made a clone of the Clip API debug tool that you can run locally yourself. See https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-yonath-74yih and scroll to the bottom of the preview for instructions on how to get it running locally.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I've followed the instructions on https://developers.meethue.com/develop/get-started-2/ and I get the CLIP API Debugger page but that's it, no matter what I put in the URL and Message Body fields, there's no response from the bridge at all. The mobile app works fine, I can control my lights via Alexa, but I can't get a response from the bridge via the CLIP API Debugger using either Chrome or Firefox.